# Cannot connect javafx Application to mysql database

Tags: java, mysql, phpmyadmin

I am trying to connect my javafx application to mysql database. There is a button named save,
[image]

which,

likewise saves Title, ISBN, Author, and Publisher to database.

**Mysql connecter version** is 2.0.14

```
    @FXML
private void savebutton(ActionEvent event) {
    try {
        String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/librarymanager";
        String uname="root";
        String pass="";
        String query="INSERT INTO `bookdetails`(`title`, `isbn`, `author`, `publisher`, `isavailable`) VALUES ("+title.getText()+","+isbn.getText()+","+author.getText()+","+publisher.getText()+","+Boolean.TRUE+")";
        Class.forName("org.gjt.mm.mysql.Driver");
        Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection(url, uname, pass);
        Statement st=con.createStatement();
        st.executeUpdate(query);
        st.close();
        con.close();
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException |SQLException ex) {
       System.out.println(ex);
    }
}
```

This is the function which is called when save button is pressed.

full controller class is...

public class FXMLDocumentController implements Initializable {

```
private Label label;
@FXML
private JFXButton save;
@FXML
private JFXButton cancel;
@FXML
private JFXTextField title;
@FXML
private JFXTextField isbn;
@FXML
private JFXTextField author;
@FXML
private JFXTextField publisher;



@Override
public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
   
    RequiredFieldValidator fortitle=new RequiredFieldValidator();
    RequiredFieldValidator forisbn=new RequiredFieldValidator();
    title.getValidators().add(fortitle);
    title.focusedProperty().addListener((ObservableValue<? extends Boolean> observable, Boolean oldValue, Boolean newValue) -> {
        if(!newValue){
            fortitle.setMessage("Enter the title");
            title.validate();
        }
    });
    isbn.getValidators().add(forisbn);
    isbn.focusedProperty().addListener((ObservableValue<? extends Boolean> observable, Boolean oldValue, Boolean newValue) -> {
        if(!newValue){
            forisbn.setMessage("Enter ISBN");
            isbn.validate();
        }
    });
}    

@FXML
private void savebutton(ActionEvent event) {
    try {
        String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/librarymanager";
        String uname="root";
        String pass="";
        String query="INSERT INTO `bookdetails`(`title`, `isbn`, `author`, `publisher`, `isavailable`) VALUES ("+title.getText()+","+isbn.getText()+","+author.getText()+","+publisher.getText()+","+Boolean.TRUE+")";
        Class.forName("org.gjt.mm.mysql.Driver");
        Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection(url, uname, pass);
        Statement st=con.createStatement();
        st.executeUpdate(query);
        st.close();
        con.close();
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException |SQLException ex) {
       System.out.println(ex);
    }
}

@FXML
private void cancelbutton(ActionEvent event) {
       Button btn=(Button)event.getSource();
       Stage stage =(Stage)btn.getScene().getWindow();
       stage.close();
}
```

Error by Netbeans IDE - **Cannot connect to MySQL server on localhost:3306. Is there a MySQL server running on the machine/port you are trying to connect to?** (java.lang.NumberFormatException).I know This error has been asked before, but i haven't done the mistake like that code.
I start server from xaamp, it started without any issue.
I can open localhost:8080/phpmyadmin/ in my browser.

I cannot point out the probable issue, would you please help me.

Answer (score 0):

It was just that the query was wrong.

Instead of

```
String query="INSERT INTO `bookdetails`(`title`, `isbn`, `author`, `publisher`, `isavailable`) VALUES ("+title.getText()+","+isbn.getText()+","+author.getText()+","+publisher.getText()+","+Boolean.TRUE+")";
```

I used

```
 String query="insert into bookdetails values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
 PreparedStatement st=con.prepareStatement(query);
                st.setString(1, title.getText());
                st.setString(2, isbn.getText());
                st.setString(3, author.getText());
                st.setString(4, publisher.getText());
                st.setBoolean(5, true);
                st.executeUpdate();
                st.close();
```

Anyways, It might help someone like me.